# How to fix Sourcemap pointing to wrong file/line?

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat, gulp-sourcemaps

I've created a Gulp Task that will compile my application with browserify/babelify and would love to have sourcemaps for it. However the sourcemaps point to the wrong file / line.

Since I'm not able to post images (because of my reputation required 10+ reputation on stackoverflow I put everything inside the gist, the gist also links to a imgur)

https://gist.github.com/EB-BartVanVliet/3c3a86dd8fcc54f24162158f1c6dc7dc

Would love some help!

Thanks,
Bart